# Rubber knockouts to fit this junction box to allow single low voltage wire to pass?

Tags: mounting, low-voltage

I am passing a single low voltage wire (actually 18/8 sprinkler)  through the interior of the garage to the exterior near the roofline, and then running the wire under the eaves. The exterior is stucco.

I bought a mounting 1 gang box that has 3/4 threaded outlets. I was going to direct the wire up toward the eave roofline. Are there rubber/cuttable gaskets that thread into the outlet so as to not leave a gaping hole? I can’t seem to find any.

[image]

Comment: If you are directing the wire up to the eave, you'd be smart to take the wire going there out of the bottom of the box, or otherwise provide a **drip loop** so the bulk of any water following the cable down drips off, rather than all trying to get into the box past whatever you use to seal it. That's standard practice for routing outside wires to boxes.

Answer (score 5):

Beware that 3/4" to your ruler is probably **nominal 1/2" pipe/conduit thread** (sized by inside of hole in the pipe, and the typical size of openings in that size/type of box.)

Anyway, doing it nicely is a **cable gland** with the right threads,

[image: Cable Gland Example] *Image Source (no affiliation, no endorsement https://cableglandsdirect.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/NPT-12-1222-CAble-Gland.jpg*

less nicely for low voltage use (only) is a tube of silicone caulking and some care in applying it. Or duct seal (a gray putty that never hardens sold in the electrical aisle, not the different product with the same name from the HVAC aisle.)

Answer (score 4):

Ecnerwal showed you the formal solution. To go cheap, grab a ["plastic threaded junction box blanking cap"](https://www.google.com/search?q=plastic+threaded+junction+box+blanking+cap&tbm=isch) and drill to suit your cable.